# jTable checkbox and removing row

Tags: java, swing

i am using jtable swing, there is checkbox inside jtable of mine, what would be the best way to removeRow of checked checkbox only?

i am using defaultTableModel and removeRow, i need to know how to get the TRUE value of ticked checkbox.

Comment: If you have a NPE then either your code is wrong or the data in the table model is bad. Post your SSCCE (http://sscce.org) demonstrating the problem.

Comment: there is NPE only if i use khachik method

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you set a `JCheckBox` to the cell editor, then you can read its value as `Boolean`.

```
class TableModel extends DefaultTableModel { 

  public TableModel(Object[] headers) { 
    super(null, headers);
  } 

  public Class getColumnClass(int c) { 
    switch (c) { 
      case 0: return Boolean.class;
      default: return String.class; 
    } 
  } 

  public boolean isCellEditable(int row, int column) { 
    if (column == 0) return true;
    return false;
  } 
}

TableModel tableModel = new TableModel(<headers as String []>);
JTable table = new JTable(tableModel);
....

TableColumnModel columnModel = table.getColumnModel();
// setting the first column to use checkboxes
columnModel.getColumn(0).setCellEditor(new DefaultCellEditor(new JCheckBox()));
...

int rowCount = tableModel.getRowCount();
for(int i=0; i<rowCount; i++) {
  Boolean selected = (Boolean)tableModel.getValueAt(0, 0);
  if(selected) {
    tableModel.removeRow(0);
  }
}
```

Comment: `Boolean selected = tableModel.getValueAt(i, 0);` not compatible type, when cast `(Boolean)tableModel.getValueAt..`, there is null pointer error

Comment: There is no need to set a custom editor. Override the getColumnClass(..) method to return Boolean as the column class and the table will use the appropriate renderer and editor. Also, when you delete rows you need to start from the end of the table and count down so you don't skip rows as you delete them.

Comment: @SOer casting fixed, thanks. `NullPointerException` on which operation?

Comment: The error message `Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NullPointerException` when cast is set on `(Boolean)tableModel.getValueAt(i, 0);`

Comment: @SOer It seems that `tableModel` is null? Am I right? See my update, I forgot the implementation of `TableModel`, sorry.

Comment: @SOer - What is the exact stack trace? Is it caused by casting, or something else?

Comment: at line here `if(selected) {`, i am using netbeans to generate GUI.

Comment: @SOer see my update again. I tried to clean up irrelevant code before posting. It is working code from my program, and when cleaning it up, I injected many mistakes, sorry... Perhaps because I'm too tired :)

Comment: i am sorry, but still same :( .. its okay, please get some rest

Comment: @SOer I want my answer to be correct and not useless :) Pleas check that you create `TableModel` instance and pass it to `JTable`s constructor; Add `null` checking: `if(selected != null && selected)` - does it work properly with it?

Answer (score 2):

If you need to implement the 'Remove all selected' you may consider the following TableModel extension, that will save some repaints (which may give better user experience):

```
import javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel;

public class RemoveCheckedRowsTableModel extends DefaultTableModel {

public void removeCheckedRows(int removeCheckBoxColumn) {
  int beginRow = 0;
  int endRow = 0;

 RangeSearch: while (beginRow < dataVector.size()) {
     while (getValueAt(beginRow, removeCheckBoxColumn).equals(Boolean.FALSE)) {
        beginRow++;
        endRow++;
        if (beginRow >= dataVector.size()) {
           break RangeSearch;
        }  
     }
     while ((endRow + 1) < dataVector.size() 
            && getValueAt((endRow + 1), removeCheckBoxColumn).equals(Boolean.TRUE)) {
        endRow++;
     }
     for (int i = beginRow; i <= endRow; i++) {
        dataVector.removeElementAt(beginRow);
     }
     fireTableRowsDeleted(beginRow, endRow);
     endRow = ++beginRow;
  }

}
}
```